# Would this count as moonlighting?

Tags: job-offer, internship, company-policy, business, moonlighting

I accepted and signed an internship offer for the summer of 2024 last spring. I love this firm (A) and i think it would be a great fit for me plus the pay is amazing. However, recently i interviewed for another great firm (B) for which the job would start this semester (fall 2023 all the way through the end of the summer of 2024). In the contract for firm A it says i shouldnt accept other full-time positions. I should add company B is not full time since i will be still in school, it will be maximum 25 hours a week. I don't want to risk losing internship A because I worked another internship prior with Company B.

Update: I have accepted both offers per the advice of a professor. Company A has no way of finding out about Company B and the time frame does not overlap. They are also not in the same industry. I desperately need money now and that contributed to the decision to take the offer with Company B to start working ASAP. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Contact company A, say you have this opportunity, and ask them whether they would consider it a conflict. We can't tell you their policies.

Comment: Based on the timeframe for each internship, would there be any overlap, to your employment? Summer 2024 doesn’t necessarily overlap Fall 2023 to Summer 2023 unless the second internship includes the entire 2024 Summer Qtr

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks like both a legal and company-specific question so it's not something that we can answer here at The Workplace.

Answer (score 6):

I think that you should respect Company A as they are giving you an opportunity with the internship.  Also, you shouldn't lie in a contract.  It could come to bite you later.

So come clean, and ask Company A what they think about it.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at a few of your statements:

> - I accepted and signed an internship offer for the summer of 2024 last spring.
> - recently i interviewed for another great firm (B) for which the job would start this semester (fall 2023 all the way through the end of
>   the summer of 2024).
> - In the contract for firm A it says "You represent and warrant you have not accepted any full-time offers of employment from any other
>   firm prior to or during your internship and you agree to notify
>   company A in the case of".

My first thought would be to start the internship with company B, and see how it goes. You will have more than 6 months of earnings with company B before you have even had a chance to start with company A.  As the time approaches where you would have a conflict decide what you want to do. You could quit the internship with B, cancel the one with A, or ask if you can do both.

Remember unless the offer letter specifies what happens if they cancel the internship, there is no guarantee that the one with company A will take place, or that the one with B will last the entire time.

Answer (score 2):

Certain types of government supported internships (e.g. the french VIE internship) are bound to the condition that you don't do another job, otherwise the support is not applicable.

You should clarify if the internship is one of these situations.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your local labor laws and determine if 25 hours a week is full time or not. For example, in my european country a "side-job" cannot be above 19 hours a week since a typical work week is considered 40 hours and anything hitting half of that time isn't a side job anymore.

After you have determinded if you're taking on a full time job with company B, you should act accordingly with company A. If it's not full time, no need to notify them. If it is, then you should honor the contract, especially since you "love" this company A and probably want to make a career with them.